# Parse.com Facebook Log-In User

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, parse-platform

I am using Parse for my app, and wanting to set up Parse's create user from facebook log-in.
I am plently familiar with how to log-in a user with Facebook JS SDK, however, trying to use Parse's system is giving me an error. When the user clicks a button it should run the log-in function. The click function works, but when parse runs the FB.login, the facebook pop up goes up and then closes without doing anything. In the console I get the error:
`POST https://api.parse.com/1/users 400 (Bad Request)`. (Also, before the error I get `FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem`.)

Here is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    // Initialize the Parse object first.
    Parse.initialize("XXXXXXXXXXX", "UUUUUUUUUU");

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
            appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true, 
            xfbml      : true
        });
        $("#fbLogin").on("click", function(){
            Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn("email", {
            success: function(user) {
            // Handle successful login
            },
            error: function(user, error) {
            // Handle errors and cancellation
            }
            });
        });
    };
    (function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
    </script>
```

Im not using a channel file, because it looks like that is out of date since facebook documentation on it is deleted. I appreciate all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this error when I have a stale Facebook login or a stale Parse user login.
Try logging out of Facebook and entering `Parse.User.logOut();` into your javascript console, and then trying again.

Comment: I know this comment is late due, but I still appreciate the attempt to help even after how long this was up answer-less! I ended up figuring it out, it was a problem with how Parse was interpreting everything and sending it to Facebook since I am using Phonegap.

I had to use the regular `FB.login()`, grab the AuthData and then just log-in with Parse normally with `Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(facebookAuthData, ...);`

And then just check if the user exists or not before I decide whether to save their info or just redirect to home.

Hope that helps someone in the future!

Comment: I was wondering what did you do to achieve that beforesave filter on the facebook login, all I can find is the Success and Error callbacks on Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn()